# How do I parse a Typoscript file?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am writing a unit test and want to check if the data in a certain typoscript file satisfies my requirements. How do I convert the text file to an array? The Typo3-Framework is available.

My google research points to using the class `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\Parser\TypoScriptParser` but I don't find usage examples ...

(Using Typo3 7.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working (but possibly there are nicer ways to do this):

```
<?php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\Parser\TypoScriptParser;

class TyposcriptTest extends \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\UnitTestCase {
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');  
    }

    protected function loadTSFile($filename) {
        $content = file_get_contents($filename);
        $parser = $this->objectManager->get(TypoScriptParser::class);
        $parser->parse($content);

        return $parser->setup;  
    }

    public function testTS() {
        $array = $this->loadTSFile('...');
        $this->assertTrue(isset($array['tx_extension.']['flexForm.']['andsoon.']]), 'Assertion failed. TS content: ' . var_export($array, true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example for TYPO3 v - 10.4.x

```
    $tsString = 'colors {
          backgroundColor = red
          fontColor = blue
        }

        [ip("123.45.*")]

          headerImage = fileadmin/img1.jpg

        [ELSE]

          headerImage = fileadmin/img2.jpg

        [GLOBAL]

        // Wonder if this works... :-)
        wakeMeUp = 7:00';

        $TSparserObject = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
              \TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\Parser\TypoScriptParser::class
        );
        $TSparserObject->parse($tsString);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($TSparserObject->setup);
        echo '</pre>';
```